# Oracle update statement multiple tables

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I am using Oracle (Still a little new to it) and each time i run the update statement below i get the following error message.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CH"."CONTRACT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE wr00262_catalogue_201310 ct SET
   ct.PORTFOLIO_ID = (SELECT ch.PORTFOLIO_ID 
                       from WR00262_CONTRACT_HEADER ch 
                       WHERE ch.PORTFOLIO_ID = ct.PORTFOLIO_ID)
   WHERE ct.NPC in (SELECT ctl.NPC 
                   FROM wr00262_contract_line ctl 
                    WHERE ctl.CONTRACT_ID = ch.CONTRACT_ID);
```

I think i may need a join but not quite sure where or how. The contract_header table does have a column called CONTRACT_ID.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It look like you are setting `PORTFOLIO_ID` to the value it already has.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. The columns in one sub-query are not visible to any other sub-query.  So try something like this:

```
UPDATE wr00262_catalogue_201310 ct SET
   PORTFOLIO_ID = (
      SELECT ch.PORTFOLIO_ID 
      from WR00262_CONTRACT_HEADER ch 
      WHERE ch.PORTFOLIO_ID = ct.PORTFOLIO_ID
   )
   WHERE ct.NPC in (
      SELECT ctl.NPC 
      FROM WR00262_CONTRACT_HEADER ch 
      join wr00262_contract_line ctl 
         on ctl.CONTRACT_ID = ch.CONTRACT_ID
      WHERE ch.PORTFOLIO_ID = ct.PORTFOLIO_ID
   );
```

Comment: You get the following when running that statement.SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: That is a problem caused by the sub-query in the `SET =` clause. So it is not a bug Egor has intoduced. You must define a WHERE clause for that sub-query which returns only one PORTFOLIO_ID.

Comment: But as @Klas points out, your stetment is a bit nonsensical anyway.

Comment: @needmorebeerformewallaby - Something is wrong with your update statement.  Look at comment by Klas.  Try to describe in words what are you trying to do.

Comment: Apologies, Klas is correct, part of the issue is down to referencing the wrong table to pull the new portfolio id from. It the table should be WR00262NEWPORTFOLIOS with a column name of NEWPORTFOLIOID

Comment: Now updated to
      UPDATE wr00262_catalogue_201310 ct SET
       PORTFOLIO_ID = (
          SELECT np.NEWPORTFOLIOID 
          from WR00262NEWPORTFOLIOS np 
          WHERE np.NEWPORTFOLIOID = ct.PORTFOLIO_ID
       )
       WHERE ct.NPC in (
          SELECT ctl.NPC 
          FROM WR00262_CONTRACT_HEADER  ch 
          join wr00262_contract_line ctl 
             on ctl.CONTRACT_ID = ch.CONTRACT_ID
          WHERE ctl.CONTRACT_ID = ch.CONTRACT_ID
       );



There is a lock of not allowing nulls on the portfolio_ID so i get that but im not sure why it is trying to pass null in.

Comment: I now get this error.


Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("WR00262_CATALOGUE_201310"."PORTFOLIO_ID") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action: